# overbrace/underbrace but with an arrow instead

Tags: amsmath

Is there a similar command to `\overbrace{foo}^{bar}` but instead of braces, an arrow pointing up/down?

EDIT: Here's a little demonstration of how I'd expect something like this to work:

[image]

And possible syntax would be `\overarrow{a=b}^{\text{theorem X}}`

Comment: How would you place the arrow? The point of the overbrace is that its width adapts to the formula, while a vertical arrow is rather thin in the horizontal direction. Not much you can do about that.

Comment: @Harald: see my edit.

Comment: Do you really want the arrow centered over "a=b"? That would become very strange if you do it over "i=m" since those letters definitely have different widths. Maybe it's better to put it just over the "=".

Comment: @Hendrik: yes, what you said makes more sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a generalized approach, providing `\overarrow[<relation>][<arrow>]{<stuff>}`. By default `<relation>` is `=` and `<arrow>` is `\uparrow` (both arguments are optional). A complement to this is provided by `\underarrow[<relation>][<arrow>]{<stuff>}` for typesetting underneath `<operator>` (`<arrow>` has the default `<downarrow>` in `\underarrow`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse

\NewDocumentCommand{\overarrow}{O{=} O{\uparrow} m}{%
  \overset{\makebox[0pt]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#3\\[0pt]\ensuremath{#2}\end{tabular}}}{#1}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\underarrow}{O{=} O{\downarrow} m}{%
  \underset{\makebox[0pt]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\ensuremath{#2}\\[0pt]#3\end{tabular}}}{#1}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \alpha &\overarrow{Theorem X}\beta & \alpha &\underarrow{Theorem X}\beta  \\
  \alpha &\overarrow[\approx]{Theorem Y}\beta & \alpha &\underarrow[\approx]{Theorem Y}\beta \\
  \alpha &\overarrow[>][\downarrow]{Theorem Z}\beta & \alpha &\underarrow[>][\uparrow]{Theorem Z}\beta
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

One difference between this typesetting and that [proposed by @Herbert](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8725/5764) is that `\stackrel` modifies the size of the upper component. Since `\overarrow` and `\underarrow` in this answer uses `tabular` to stack the items, no size adjustment is visible.

[`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) provides the interface for mixing optional/mandatory arguments.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\overUnderArrow{\@ifnextchar[\overUnderArrow@i{\overUnderArrow@i[]}}
\def\overUnderArrow@i[#1]#2#3{% #1 under #2 over #3 main argument
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\array[b]{c}\overset{\text{#2}}{\uparrow}\\#3\endarray
  \else\ifx\relax#2\relax
    \array[t]{c}#3\\\underset{\text{#1}}{\downarrow}\endarray
  \else
    \array{c}\overset{\text{#2}}{\uparrow}\\#3\\\underset{\text{#1}}{\downarrow}\endarray
  \fi\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[
  \overUnderArrow[TheoremX]{TheoremX}{\alpha = \beta}
  \overUnderArrow{TheoremX}{\alpha = \beta}
  \overUnderArrow[TheoremX]{}{\alpha = \beta}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The syntax is `\overUnderArrow[below]{above}{main entry}`. 
It is also possible to extend the definition for variable arrows direction.

Comment: is it possible to modify this to a down arrow and position everything beneath? also how can I add some padding around the arrow? it's too close sometimes http://i.imgur.com/N1MHu.png

Comment: how should I know what and how you _extracted_ something from my solution ...

Comment: I'm talking about your solution as it is shown here.. is it possible to alter it to do what I asked?

Comment: I added a command for a down arrow, see answer