# Text under or over

Tags: symbols

I wish to make such a explanation under the formulas:[image]

What is the easiest way?

Comment: Welcome to SE! Search through SE. Similar question has been asked here many times.

Comment: To be fair, it's quite hard to know what to search for, but this might get you started http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8720/overbrace-underbrace-but-with-an-arrow-instead

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use a combination of `\underset`/`\overset` and `\substack` macros to place the explanatory text and the down/up-arrows below/above their associated formulas. With `\substack`, you won't have to provide lots of `\scriptstyle` (or similar) font-sizing instructions.

As the second display equation below shows, you may want to introduce linebreaks in some of the `\underset` and `\overset` constructs in order to make the overall equation a bit more compact.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[
\int \underset{\substack{\downarrow \\ \text{Integrand}}}{f(x)} dx = 
\underset{\substack{\downarrow \\ \text{Anti-deriverte til  $f(x)$}}}{F(x)} + 
\overset{\substack{\text{Integrasionkonstant}\\\uparrow}}{C} 
\]

\bigskip

\[
\int \underset{\substack{\downarrow \\ \text{Integrand}}}{f(x)} dx = 
\underset{\substack{\downarrow \\ \text{Anti-deriverte} \\ \text{til  $f(x)$}}}{F(x)} + 
\overset{\substack{\text{Integrasion-}\\ \text{konstant}\\ \uparrow}}{C} 
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\int \underset{\underset{\scriptstyle\text{Integrand}}{\scriptstyle\downarrow}}{f(x)} dx = 
\underset{\underset{\scriptstyle\text{Anti-derivative til } f(x)}{\scriptstyle\downarrow}}{F(x)} + 
\overset{\underset{\scriptstyle\uparrow}{\scriptstyle\text{Integrasionkonstant}}}{C} 
\]

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

---

If there are many situations like the above, perhaps it will make life less complicated if you define your own set of macros for above-legend and below-legend.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

% #1: math symbol
% #2: legend
\def\alegend#1#2{\overset{\underset{\scriptstyle\uparrow}{\scriptstyle\text{#2}}}{#1}}
\def\blegend#1#2{\underset{\underset{\scriptstyle\text{#2}}{\scriptstyle\downarrow}}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\[
\int \blegend{f(x)}{Integrand} dx = 
\blegend{F(x)}{Anti-derivative til $f(x)$} + 
\alegend{C}{Integrasionkonstant}
\]

\end{document}
```

This makes your code cleaner and easier to maintain.

Comment: This is a great answer, but in your undersets you seem to have small arrows and big text and in your overset you have a big arrow and small text

Comment: @Au101 Thanks for pointing it out. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

This does not look like your picture, but it might be close enough.  In fact, in my opinion it's a bit clearer.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
$\int
\underbrace{f(x)}_{\mbox{Integrand}} d x =
\underbrace{F(x)}_{\mbox{Anti-derivative till $f(x)$}} +
\overbrace{C}^{\mbox{integration constant}}$
\end{document}
```

Really, using \mbox like I did is wrong, because you get the wrong font size (too big).  If you don't mind loading an extra package, amstext lets you do it right.  (No need to load it explicitly if you already loaded amsmath.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amstext}
\begin{document}
$\int
\underbrace{f(x)}_{\text{Integrand}} d x =
\underbrace{F(x)}_{\text{Anti-derivative till $f(x)$}} +
\overbrace{C}^{\text{integration constant}}$
\end{document}
```

And now the font size is right.

Comment: I was looking for a way to keep the same font size, so `\mbox{}` did it for me! :-)